# Is there a way to return a custom error when Newtonsoft.JSON deserialization fails?

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to change the ResponseBody when a request fails because deserialization to an Enum wasn't successful. The application is a .NET Core 3 API.

I've got the following property on one of my entities:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
```

where Attribute is the following Enum:

```
public enum Attribute
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "value-1")]
        value1,
        [EnumMember(Value = "value-2")]
        value2,
        [EnumMember(Value = "some-value")]
        somevalue
    }
```

When I try to POST a body with a wrong value for the Enum:

```
{
  "attribute": "wrong-value"
}
```

My endpoint returns a 400 with a Newtonsoft error and I'd like to return a ResponseBody created by me instead.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "attribute": [
            "Error converting value \"wrong-value\" to type 'Project.Attribute'. Path 'attribute', line 10, position 24."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|1cf19d18-4577510ef4de1g923."
}
```

Is there a way to intercept such error with a middleware and return a custom ResponseBody?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to create a `StringEnumConverter` class:

```
internal class StringEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Attribute>("'" + reader.Value.ToString() + "'");
            }
            catch
            {
                var tr = reader as JsonTextReader;
                throw new Exception($"Error converting value \"{reader.Value.ToString()}\" to type \"{objectType.ToString()}\". Path \"{tr.Path}\", line {tr.LineNumber}, position {tr.LinePosition}.");
            }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then while trying to deserialize my JSON string I would catch any exception like:

```
string json = "{'attribute': 'value1x'}";

try
{
    MyClass r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

That way my Exception would have the appropriate message. Of course, you have to keep in mind that this is only for deserializing strings to the `Attribute` type (perhaps the name should be changed to `StringToAttributeConverter` for more readability). You will have to find a slightly more generic way of doing it for all different types of enums (maybe by using a generic...) if possible.